# embedded webview shows location bar after inactive InputConnection message

Tags: android, webview

I am developing a simple app, with only an embedded chrome webview that communicates with an embedded http server . There's almost no Android java code in the project. 
The web app runs fine for about 5 minutes, with the webview fullscreen, and javascript doing all kinds of dom manipulation. The webview has none of the typical browser decoration, only the content area is showing.

After ca. 5 minutes, I see a message in logcat: `W/IInputConnectionWrapper﹕ showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection`, and then the embedded chrome webview suddenly shows like a browser. It has a location bar, search, favorites etc...

*Now I realize somehow the normal browser is launched, with the same url as my webview, so it shows the same poster as my webview. But why? My app isn't launching anything!*

This screws up my whole application, which uses the android+browser combo to show poster like information, and I'd like to get rid of the behavior.

My app doesn't have or need *any* input, but it needs to run continuously, typically on an android device connected to a large monitor.

Would anyone have any info on solving this issue?

The part of my code that deals with setting up the webview is trivial:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(webView1);
    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    {
        WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
    }
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

and after that I set up the internal web server, and finally:

```
    String index_html = String.format(Locale.US, "http://localhost:%d/test/index.html", port);
    webView.loadUrl(index_html);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> then the embedded chrome webview suddenly shows like a browser

This will occur if the user taps on a traditional hyperlink, or if the server issues a redirect. The default behavior of `WebView` is to load the destination URL in the user's browser (more accurately: it uses `ACTION_VIEW` to launch something to view that URL).

You can call `setWebViewClient()` on the `WebView`, supplying your own `WebViewClient` subclass, where you implement `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` and handle the event yourself, such as by calling `loadUrl()` on the `WebView` to keep the URL within your app.

Comment: Thank you! I just realized I didn't see my app anymore, but the default browser. I'm sure this will solve the issue!

Comment: Your suggestion worked like a charm! I'm going to buy your http://commonsware.com/Android/ book. Thanks